# Why is my multiprocessing function map_async getting stuck?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

My multithreading operation hangs when calling the map_async method with a splitted DataFrame as input. What can cause this problem?

I tried to look if it mattered if the splitted DataFrames where evenly sized or not. Also I tested both Pool.map and Pool.map_sync. My CPU is around 80% for four cores. Furthermore, I looked into different question threads about this subject. One of the problems was to give an empty iterable as argument to one of the map functions.

```py
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test(df):
    print(df['ELEM'].iloc[0])

filename = "ABC.xlsx"     

df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0) # (135, 28) DataFrame

p = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 # = 3 

splitted = np.array_split(df, p) # 3 * (45, 28) DataFrames

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=p)

processs = [(splitted_df_pi) for splitted_df_pi in splitted] # 3 * (45, 28) DataFrames

result = pool.map_async(test, processs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I expect the process not to go on forever. However, it seems to be. I am not completely sure where to look, or how to get to the source of this problem. I hope somebody can shed some light on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever solve it? For me it was a memory issue, maybe it's the same issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784038/python-multiprocessing-application-is-getting-stuck-in-docker-container