# Python multiprocessing application is getting stuck in docker container

Tags: python, docker, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run a multiprocessing Python application to speedup and parallel my tasks.
My application is using a simple multiprocessing `Pool` and running within docker container with limited resources.

I have noticed that my application is getting stuck from time to time; It's never end/terminated but nothing moves (tasks stop running, no logs).

After digging around, I found that it's a memory issue: if there's is not enough RAM the application keeps running (doing nothing), but if I add more memory to the container, all tasks finish successfully and the container finish and exit.

I was expecting for either:

1. A retry mechanism.
2. An exception (of a dying Process, OOM, etc.).
3. A log message with a proper severity.

None of them happen. Is there a way to make `multiprocessing` to give me some feedback instead of being so quite?

Below you can find a simple reproducible [example](https://github.com/itayB/aiomultiprocess-mem/tree/multi), with a stupid task that's only eat the memory. Running it with `--memory=2g` will stuck forever with no indication, while running it with `--memory=3g` finish successfully after a few minutes:

```
docker build -t multiprocess_mem .
docker run --rm --memory=2g --cpus=5 multiprocess_mem
```

Application's tree structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
└── multi
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    └── app.py
```

`app.py`

```
import logging
import os
import sys

from multiprocessing import Pool

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def init_logger():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)-15s %(process)d %(levelname)-18.18s %(message)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d]",
        stream=sys.stdout
    )
    logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def my_mem_task(task_id):
    logger.info(f"T{task_id:03} started!")
    data = []
    for i in range(100_000):
        data.append([i] * 1_000)
    logger.info(f"T{task_id:03} {len(data)}")


def main():
    init_logger()
    number_of_processes = int(os.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES", "4"))
    logger.info("creating pool")
    with Pool(
            processes=number_of_processes,
            initializer=init_logger,
    ) as pool:
        task_ids = [task_id for task_id in range(150)]
        pool.map(my_mem_task, task_ids)
        pool.close()
        logger.info("processes pool closed")
        pool.join()
        logger.info("all processes are done")
```

`__main__.py`:

```
from multi.app import main


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /
COPY multi /multi
CMD ["python", "-m", "multi"]
```

Lastly, `exec` into the "stuck" container shows that both parent & child processes are still running:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
root@ff5ca6bf92f3:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
...
root@ff5ca6bf92f3:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 18:06 ?        00:00:00 python -m multi
root         9     1 55 18:06 ?        00:01:24 python -m multi
root        10     1 55 18:06 ?        00:01:24 python -m multi
root        15     1 29 18:07 ?        00:00:36 python -m multi
root        19     1 28 18:07 ?        00:00:30 python -m multi
root        20     0  0 18:07 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root       346    20  0 18:09 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. try concurrent.futures process executor

Different libraries handle cases like these differently. Might fail more gracefully under your specific circumstances.

2. psutils and manual memory allocation logging

If you are building this into a production process, this is a must given errors you've encountered so far.